# Read Lucene Index client-side

Tags: lucene, indexing, client

I would read Lucene index client-side, ie without any server.

The index folder is in local. In fact, I have the folder of a website, inside there is a folder containing several docs(xml) and the lucene index.
In the doc, there is elements like

```
 <link ref="A-B-C">a link</link>
```

and in the lucene index, A-B-C refer to a path like _hat_A-B-C.xml. 
So I would read Lucene index with JS or other languages client-side.

I find [lucene.js](https://github.com/dennycd/lucene.js) but I think it use Node.js and so we must use a server.

Which tool can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Let me try: you want to read lucene index from where? from client machine? or how? strongly consider you to edit your question, to improve it's readability

Comment: I edit, sorry if is not clear, i don't speak english very well. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm seeking such "tool" as well. I need to read Lucene indexes with javascript on the client side. Read Lucene indexes on the server side would also do the trick, but read the indexes on the client side would be preferable. I'm going to take a look at [lucene.js](https://github.com/dennycd/lucene.js) as the OP suggested, but any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Resolved! I've created a plugin Cordova to make this. If you've interested, I will probably upload it.